# Extracting last layers of keras model as a submodel

Tags: python, keras

Say we have a convolutional neural network M. I can extract features from  images by using

```
extractor = Model(M.inputs, M.get_layer('last_conv').output)
features = extractor.predict(X)
```

How can I get the model that will predict classes using `features`?

I can't use the following lines because it requires the input of the model to be a placeholder.

```
predictor = Model([M.get_layer('next_layer').input], M.outputs)
pred = predictor.predict(features)
```

I also can't use `K.function` because later I want to use it as part of another model, so I will be appliyng predictor to tf.tensor, not np.array.

Comment: What is the problem with using a placeholder or an Input layer? That is the correct way.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro How do I stack **trained** layers of the predictor on top of new Input layer?

Comment: With the functional API, you just use your model as it were a layer: in = Input(...)  inter  = yourModel(in) final = Dense(10)(inter)

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, you can't "create a model" starting from a layer that is already connected to an input. That's is the error message.

Comment: @DanielMöller You can if you define your model properly before training.

Comment: That's why Oli Brum's answer got a vote :)

Comment: I think you can still use one model but set trainable=False for last layers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not the nicest solution, but it works:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten

def cnn():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(28, 28, 1), name='l_01'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='l_02'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='l_03'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25, name='l_04'))
    model.add(Flatten(name='l_05'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', name='l_06'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5, name='l_07'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='l_08'))
    return model

def predictor(input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(name='l_05', input_shape=(12, 12, 64)))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', name='l_06'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5, name='l_07'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='l_08'))
    return model

cnn_model = cnn()
cnn_model.save('/tmp/cnn_model.h5')

predictor_model = predictor(cnn_model.output.shape)
predictor_model.load_weights('/tmp/cnn_model.h5', by_name=True)
```

Comment: Yes.... so far this is the only solution I found for that case, recreating the relevant part of the model exactly.

Comment: Yes, I also resorted to rebuilding the predictor and loading weights. `by_name` is useful. But I think there's gotta be a cleaner solution. I'll accept the answer if we don't come up with the better one soon.

Answer (score 2):

Every layer in the model is indexed. So if you know which layers you need, you could loop through them, copying them into a new model. This operation should copy the weights inside the layer as well.

Here's a model (from Oli Blum's answer):

```
  model = Sequential()
  # add some layers
  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(28, 28, 1), name='l_01'))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='l_02'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='l_03'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25, name='l_04'))
  model.add(Flatten(name='l_05'))
  model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', name='l_06'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5, name='l_07'))
  model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='l_08'))
```

Say you wanted the last three layers:

```
def extract_layers(main_model, starting_layer_ix, ending_layer_ix):
  # create an empty model
  new_model = Sequential()
  for ix in range(starting_layer_ix, ending_layer_ix + 1):
    curr_layer = main_model.get_layer(index=ix)
    # copy this layer over to the new model
    new_model.add(curr_layer)
  return new_model
```

Comment: This is sweet! Does this bring the state of the layers over too? I.e. the weights?

Comment: Little mistake : `extract_layers` should return `new_model` instead of the undefined variable `extracted_layers`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

- If you are going to throw away the feature extractor afterwards
- If you plan on training the feature extractor later

If you are going to use the extracted features but you don't intend on training the model used to generate them, you could use the predict method to get the features as you did:

```
features = extractor.predict(X)
```

then save its output to a file (np.save or cPickle or whatever).
After that you could use that new dataset as the input to a new model.

If you plan on training the feature extractor later you'll need to stack the two networks as seen here with vgg as feature extractor https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4576:

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
vgg16_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

input = Input(batch_shape=vgg16_model.output_shape)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(input)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predict = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
top_model = Model(input, predict)

top_model.load_weights(os.path.join(data_path, 'VGG16Classifier.hdf5'))  

input = Input(shape=(3, img_width, img_height))
x = vgg16_model(input)
predict = top_model(x)
model = Model(input, predict)
```

**PS: This example uses channels first ordering. If you are using tensorflow you should change the shape to shape=(img_width, img_height,3 )**

Comment: I guess I can see the solution in the code you provided. I will be able to test it later.
But the main problem is in the predictor, not extractor. Did you mean predictor?
I will be throwing away the extractor and will only use fixed weights in predictor (without training it).

Comment: If you are going to throw away the extractor it's simple, just get the output  data from the model. When I say "predict" I mean use the extractor.predict as in getting its output. After this output you are basically with new a data set as any other.  Build your symbolic model with keras/tensorflow and pass the data in the model's fit method as if it was any other data set with a map vector->label

Comment: I am loading the features from extractor.predict(X) as any other data. The problem is to get the **symbolic model of the predictor** part with the trained weights. Unfortunately, your answer doesn't solve this problem. :(

Comment: You want to split the top and the convolutional parts of the network, is that it?

Comment: Yes, and keep those parts trained. After the split I need to use the top as part of another network