# Extract subnetwork from Keras Sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a very simple autoencoder network similar to this example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(8, activation="relu", name="latent_space"),
        layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name="decode_32"),
        layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(128, activation="sigmoid"),
        ])

model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

# Extract subnetwork here after training
```

I would like to know if it is possible to feed data to the `latent_space` layer such that I can afterwards extract the activations from layer `decode_32`? Ideally I would like to `crop` a subnetwork after training with the `latent_space` layer as the input and the `decode_32` layer as the output layer. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just get your desired input and output layers and create a new model with them. In your case, making sure you specify an input shape:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(128, activation="relu", input_shape=(15,)),
    layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(8, activation="relu", name="latent_space"),
    layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name="decode_32"),
    layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(128, activation="sigmoid"),
])

model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

in_layer = model.get_layer("latent_space")
out_layer = model.get_layer("decode_32")

sub_model = keras.Model(inputs=in_layer.input, outputs=out_layer.output)
```

`sub_model` will be a model with just your selected layers, like you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689617/13706904) fits your question?

```
def extract_layers(main_model, starting_layer_ix, ending_layer_ix) :
  # create an empty model
  new_model = Sequential()
  for ix in range(starting_layer_ix, ending_layer_ix + 1):
    curr_layer = main_model.get_layer(index=ix)
    # copy this layer over to the new model
    new_model.add(curr_layer)
  return new_model
```

If you prefer selecting your subnetwork with the names of the first and last layers, the [`get_layer`](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/get_layer.html) method also has an argument for the layer's name, but an easier solution would be to retrieve the indexes of the layers to select thanks to the `layer.name` argument.

That way, you just have to modify the previous function by adding

```
layer_names = [layer.name for layer in main_model.layers]
starting_layer_ix = layer_names.index(starting_layer_name)
ending_layer_ix = layer_names.index(ending_layer_name)
```

Comment: should return `new_model` instead of the undefined variable

Comment: You're right, I haven't seen this mistake in the original piece of code. Thanks for pointing it !

Comment: @RandomGuy Is it also possible to pass the names of the layers instead of having to know the layer's index?

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope it better fits you now